# downloaded file extention has a ";" in it

Tags: php

I am using a force download script to avoid streaming of mp3 files in my site.
It works in my PC , but in my android phone , download doesn't start !!
And in my android tablet , the file extension changes into  filename.mp3;
So the file has to be renamed to work !!

What is the problem here ?

```
<?php
$file=str_replace("\0", null, htmlspecialchars($_GET['file']));
$name = $_GET['name'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$name.";");
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

I just made a small change , and it work fine it tablet .
But my android phone is not downloading it .

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename = $name");
```

Comment: `Content-type: octet/stream` — Please use the correct mime type for your files.

Comment: Let's see who gets **the points**.... *pass the popcorn* - No answer from me, I'm having **lunch**. I don't work `while` **{on break;}** ;-)

Comment: don't use this code. you're allow people to download **ANY** file on your server for which they know the path. There goes your /etc/passwd and other critical private data...

Comment: **Read up** on Mime Types => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME - http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

Answer (score 2):

Your filename header looks incorrect. Try this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
```

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon on the end of the file name:

```
.";");
```

Comment: Yes , I found that , but why it is not downloading in android phone browser?

Comment: @Shijil As `Quentin` noted in his first comment, and I quote *"Please use the correct mime type for your files."*. That's most probably why. Today's technology has gotten that more strict, if one is not used in conjunction with the file type(s) used.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `;` after the filename. Based on [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) Just a quoted string

The header should appear like this (note space before filename and quotes around the filename)

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to header ('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"') it should work.

If you look at [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), you'll notice in 19.5.1 that the semicolon only separates the disposition-type (ie "attachment") from the filename and the filename is supposed to be a quoted string.

Comment: @MarcB Well, he's "partially" right. Too bad **SO** doesn't have a **-0.5** option. ;-) 50% of 50%

Comment: Yup! Posted too hastily. Fixed now.